# Is it possible to be reimbursed by the NHS or government for price difference of gluten-free food?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, medical

I've heard years ago that if one with gluten allergy saves receipts then since the diet is their medical treatment then the government reimburses the cost difference between GF and non-GF options. However upon searching all I was able to find were materials about certain basic foods like beads and mixes and previously pizza bases etc. Being "prescribed" by the NHS.

Comment: https://www.england.nhs.uk/medicines-2/medicines-optimisation/prescribing-gluten-free-foods-in-primary-care-guidance-for-ccgs-faqs/#what-gf-foods-have-ccgs-prescribed-in-the-past

Comment: 1. Then why does the NHS prescribe gluten free food?

Comment: Food isn't medical treatment, it is simply food. Eat whatever suits you. If I am allergic to peanuts a steak isn't medicine, it is a steak. I would just avoid eating peanuts, that's all.

Comment: “Prescribe” in this context just means the doctor’s recommended diet.  Do you get a written prescription?  Do you have to pick up your diet from the pharmacy?  Is your diet only available if you have a prescription?  No?  Right then, don’t eat gluten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are prescription basic staple foods that must be in the prescribing formulary with restricted variety, which may be free or reimbursed, depending on your place of residence and circumstances.

If the government did reimburse the cost difference, it would be very likely be on the information section of [Coeliac UK](https://www.coeliac.org.uk/information-and-support/coeliac-disease/once-diagnosed/prescriptions/). As no mention of such reimbursements can be found, it is likely what you have heard is false.

---

In some countries, but not the United Kingdom, medical expenses are tax deductible. This does not mean the government reimburses the cost of medical expenses, but that medical expenses reduces the *taxable income* based on which a tax rate is determined and applied.

Some jurisdictions (e.g. [Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/deductions-credits-expenses/lines-33099-33199-eligible-medical-expenses-you-claim-on-your-tax-return/details-medical-expenses.html)) do accept the difference between gluten-free food and "normal" food as part of medical expenses, provided that documentations are *meticulously* available. In other jurisdictions (e.g. Switzerland), a lumpsum deduction is available to compensate.